# NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription German Translation doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

My Problem is, I can´t translate this key `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` all other keys like `NSCameraUsageDescription` work. Also in other Languages like Czech the translation for `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` works, but not in the German InfoPlist.strings.

Answer (score 1):

in case you haven't found the solution this worked for me: I followed the directions in [Localizing Property List Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-102276), manually created an InfoPlist.strings file with German translations in de.lproj directory and added the file in xcode.

I am using xcode 8 and swift 3.